# Regular expression in JavaScript to match a given string

Tags: javascript

I have a string like below

> `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?channel=rdc-ldp-streetview&client=sourcemaps`

How do i check whether my variable value returned matches with:

> `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview`

Comment: refer `String.indexOf()` will help you

Comment: You don't need regular expressions for fixed strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if one string contains another substring in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

ES6

```
str.startsWith('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview');
```

ES5

```
str.indexOf('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview') === 0
```